# Eigendecomposition of a matrix implies invertibility?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Does existence of Eigendecomposition of a matrix imply that it is invertible? That is, does the existence of n independent eigenvectors of a matrix imply that the matrix is invertible? If so, what is the reasoning behind eigenvectors and invertibility being connected? It seems intuitively wrong based on what I've learnt.

For instance, suppose A has n independent eigenvectors. Then the eigendecomposition exists:

$$A = PDP^{-1}$$

Then A is invertible?

EDIT: link to another question on this topic: [For a square matrix $A$ presence of $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors implies full rank, thereby invertible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182886/for-a-square-matrix-a-presence-of-n-linearly-independent-eigenvectors-implie?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: No. Any diagonal matrix has a full set of eigenvectors, but any of the diagonal elements can be zero leaving the matrix singular.

Comment: In particular, the $0$ matrix is diagonal, and so if you pick your favourite invertible matrix $P$, then $0 = P0P^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks, so the zero eigenvalue is the pathological case. What if we guarantee that we don't have a zero eigenvalue?

Comment: @information_interchange Having an eigenvalue equal $0$ means that the matrix is not invertible. If there had to be a case, it has to correspond to the eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: So I suppose the follow-up/corollary of this question is: does having $n$ independent eigenvectors tell us anything about the matrix? It seems like we can form an eigenbasis, which seems useful, but if we have the possibility of 0 eigenvalue it seems like that destroys any usefulness

Comment: You can cook up cases of matrices having $n$ independent eigenvectors and rank $k$, for every $k=1,\dots,n$.

Comment: Why does having a nontrivial kernel make diagonalization useless?

Comment: Hmm I see, so invertibility is not a main property/goal of diagonalization.  But what would be the point of diagonalizing a matrix when one of the rows in our $D$ will be all 0? I guess it still allows for solving $A^n x$ quickly

Comment: Indeed, found a source that invertibility is "generally" unrelated to diagonalization: https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/diagonalization.html